# What does this command do on Linux? It is eating my CPU.

Tags: mysql, linux, cpu-usage, command

I have a VPS and I am hosting a game site on it. Recently my CPU went to 3000% and memory is going near full.

When I checked the processes I found this process eating the CPU:

```
Pid-1571 (Trace) (Kill) 
Owner-mysql 
Priority-0 
CPU %-52.7 
Memory %-4.4
Command:
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/domain.com.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/domain.com.pid
```

What does this command do? Why is it running? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is MySQL, a database engine. I guess your site utilizes a MySQL database and the SQL queries are not optimal or the engine is not properly tuned. Anyway you can't simply stop it because your site will stop too.

Comment: is there is anyway to know what the SQL queries that eat up the cpu?

Comment: Sure, you can enable a mysql slow query log: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html. There is a tool to process and summarize this log in the Maatkit utils package: http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on distribution, try

```
service mysql stop
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mysql* stop
```

Be warned. Shutting it down will put you site offline, as it is the database.